# Java program thowing NullpointerException for the below piece of code

Tags: java, debugging, nullpointerexception

Not gettiing the hit and Miss places of the attack. Getting an output put it is incorrect. Iam using grid class location interface for ship class and no ship class.

Iam having a location interface that just implements the Ship class and no Ship class.How to debug the in correct output

Comment: Javascript tag removed as this question appears to have nothing to do with the Javascript programming language. Code formatted better in question.

Comment: This is almost certainly because `grid[i][j] == null`.

Comment: Your NoShip class looks a little messy, for instance attack() sets hit to true, but then returns isShip which is false. if you call wasHit() as well, without setting "hit" to anything, then it will throw the null pointer because you didn't set hit to any value

Comment: I don't understand the name `NoShip`.

Comment: You shouldn't be using wrapper types for this program. Stick with primitive types where needed.

Answer (score 6):

Note `hit` is not a `boolean` but a `Boolean` object, and was never initialized, so it is `null`. On [autounboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), it cannot be convert to a `boolean`, so a `NullPointerException` was thrown.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I have initialised boolean to true for ship class and false to no ship class but in the output rather than showing the hit by X and miss by 0 it shows all the original ship places by X.

Comment: Is the original problem solved? Sorry but I don't quite get what you are asking, you might get a better chance if you ask a separate question if it is indeed another question (so you can explain it better).

Comment: I want to indicate miss by 0, hit by X in grid.I have a location interface that implements ship and NoShip class. Im using          if( grid[i][j].wasHit() && grid[i][j].isShip()){
                    System.out.print("X ");
                          } else if(grid[i][j].wasHit()&& !grid[i][j].isShip() ){
                    System.out.print("0 ");
                } else{
                    System.out.print("- ");

Comment: I want to indicate miss by 0, hit by X in grid.I have a location interface that implements ship and NoShip class. Im using          if( grid[i][j].wasHit() && grid[i][j].isShip()){
                    System.out.print("X ");
                          } else if(grid[i][j].wasHit()&& !grid[i][j].isShip() ){
                    System.out.print("0 ");
                } else{
                    System.out.print("- ");                                          public class Ship implements Location {
 public boolean isShip(){
            return true; /* true it has been hit yet*/
        }
correct

Comment: You could post some more code although it probably does not fit in this question, but from your current posted code I see no cause for what you described. FYI, you double posted:)

Comment: check Grid class in my original post. Main class: public static void main(String[] args) {
        game = new Grid(SHIPs);

        do {
            final int menuSelection = getMenuSelection();
            switch (menuSelection) {
                case 1:
                    try {
                        System.out.println("\nEnter Coordinate to attack");
                        if (game.attackCoordinate(getCoordinate("X"), getCoordinate("Y"))) {
                            System.out.println("\nHit!");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("\nMiss!");

Answer (score 0):

```
I would like to know why we get NullpointerException and how to debug this code
to have it working.
```

Well, `NullPointerException` throw on `NoShip.java:30`, check this ,you must initialize hit
or  change `Boolean`  to `boolean` ,if you not init ,so return null,throw `NullPointerException`

Comment: I want to indicate miss by 0, hit by X in grid.I have a location interface that implements ship and NoShip class. Im using          if( grid[i][j].wasHit() && grid[i][j].isShip()){
                    System.out.print("X ");
                          } else if(grid[i][j].wasHit()&& !grid[i][j].isShip() ){
                    System.out.print("0 ");
                } else{
                    System.out.print("- ");                                          public class Ship implements Location {
 public boolean isShip(){
            return true; /* true it has been hit yet*/
        }
correct?